# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNull cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Getting below Exception while trying to read byte array using iText PdfReader,

Below is my code, I'm able to open this file in Acrobat reader

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bFile);
```

Exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNull cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader$PageRefs.iteratePages(PdfReader.java:3712)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader$PageRefs.iteratePages(PdfReader.java:3743)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader$PageRefs.readPages(PdfReader.java:3548)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader$PageRefs.<init>(PdfReader.java:3518)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader$PageRefs.<init>(PdfReader.java:3496)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPages(PdfReader.java:1142)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:659)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:244)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:234)`

Im using iText 5.4.4, I couldn't find much details in googling. It looks PDF has some issues, couldn't get whats the issue. Below is the excerpts from PDF

```
%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Lang (en-US)
/StructTreeRoot 39 0 R
/MarkInfo <<
/Marked true
>>
/Pages 187 0 R
/AcroForm 350 0 R
/OCProperties 2131 0 R
/Outlines 2531 0 R
/OpenAction <<
/Type /Action
/S /GoTo
/D [ 3 0 R /XYZ 0 792 0 ]
>>
/ViewerPreferences <<
/HideToolbar false
/HideMenubar false
/HideWindowUI false
/FitWindow false
/CenterWindow false
>>
```

**UPDATE:** After debugging I found that `/Pages 187 0 R` is the problem. If I change to `/Pages 2 0 R` then it works. Could some please help me what does that `/Pages` refers ?

Comment: please provide more context. We can't even see what call caused the exception!

Comment: Edited my question, Hope it helps

Comment: How you filled the byte array? Maybe it's already broken there?

Comment: Using FileInputStream, The same code works for thousands of PDF. Its just not working for this PDF

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with this pdf. Can you open it with a pdf reader?

Comment: I can't, Im getting this exception while reading the PDF using PdfReader

Comment: Please share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: Sorry, Its kind of confidential document.

Comment: As you are using an AGPL version of iText, you are probably an iText customer. iText customers can share documents privately on the closed issue tracker at iText Software. This way, we can ensure the confidentiality of your customer (just like you treat documents from your customer in a confidential way, we do so with our customers).

Comment: *Could some please help me what does that /Pages refers* - **Pages** points to the root of the page tree.

Comment: I can't understand whats the problem with 187 0 R in the header. Actually the page has 183 pages only, is it something related to number of pages.  When I tried changing to 183 0 R its not all opening in Acrobat. When I changed to 2 0 R then it shows 2 pages only which is not correct. Im not sure how to fix it.